React-Core-RCTI18nStrings, React-Core-CoreModuleHeaders-RCTI18nStrings, both are generating RCTI18nStrings.bundle
React-Core-RCTI18nStrings,React-Core-CoreModuleHeaders-RCTI18nStrings, both are generating RCTI18nStrings.bundle
Tried
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| if target.name == "React-Core-RCTI18nStrings" target.remove_from_project end end
                  &

installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| if target.name == "React-Core-CoreModuleHeaders-RCTI18nStrings" || "React-CoreRCTI18nStrings" target.remove_from_project end end
